# Is it possible to style a checked QToolButton using QSS?

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets, qtoolbar, qtoolbutton

Obviously, this applies only to checkable QToolButtons.

The light blue background and border isn't as nice on my app as a light red background. (The code below has red background just as an example.)

I've tried:

```css
QToolButton:pressed {
    background: red;
}
```

as well as `QToolButton:checked` and `QToolButton:active`.

And I'm here since neither worked. Hard to find anything in the Qt documentation about this. Might have missed something if there is.

Is it possible to change the style of a checked QToolButton via the style sheet? Or do I have to update their CSS dynamically whenever they're clicked?

Answer (score 2):

So apparently

```css
QToolButton:checked {
    background:red;
}
```

works perfectly fine.

The result shows after running the program, but not in Qt's UI interface.